# how to achieve consistent fps in java game

Tags: java

Developing a game in java, using JFrame.

My question is regarding a "sprite" which appropriately increments its image, displayed every step/frame in-game.

I have a timer set to 33 milliseconds or one 30th of a second (30 fps).

It functions correctly, as in it appropriately prints in the terminal "Test" every 33 milliseconds, but what I see in the window is different. while I have a mouse in the window, the sprite appropriately swaps images, appearing to be moving, but its refresh rate drops drastically if the mouse is not in the window or not moving.

I have a JPanel in the frame and a JLabel within it. When the timer triggers, JLabel.setIcon() is called, which recieves the next image in the sprite.

Repaint, revalidate has no effect. The first ~2 seconds the sprite moves at expected speeds, after that it slows to approximately 2fps, unless I move the mouse cursor at which point it functions at aproximately 30 fps again for approximately 2 seconds.

Comment: there's a lot of potential issues, you'll have to run your code under a profiler to see where it's losing performance

Comment: Sounds like everything is running on a single UI thread

Comment: Maybe the images are too big?

Comment: It seems clear to me that this is inbuilt in an effort to minimise jframe resource consumption. Its refresh rate is dropped if it is not "expected" to refresh, such as when the mouse is inactive. How can I overwrite this

Comment: Image is 70x60 pixels. What does it mean everything is running on one UI thread. And there is only one JPanel and one jlabel on screen

Comment: I had a similar issue recently, to fix the problem I found this line of code, that need to be just after you render your graphics : `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`. I'm curious to know if it fix the problem for you ! (I can't explain to you what it does, but it fixed the problem for me)

Comment: Swing isn't made for games and while it is possible to make some games using it it will quickly become a mess of workarounds around the framework. You should consider switching to an actual game framework (such as libgdx)

Comment: Java isn't made for games. Even after you solve this particular issue, it will still lag. Don't shoot the messenger, just trying to save you time.

Comment: Java isn't made for games ? Well, Notch wouldn't agree with you. I think one could do games in Java, you just need to be efficient and keep it light. But your point of view is interesting, I never heard that it wouldn't be "for games", so it makes me reconsider what I am doing right now :) (I'm not using irony, if it seems ambiguous).

Comment: Thank you. Will switch to a different programming language.

Comment: @rustyx it's not that Java isn't made for games. It's the absence of good and popular frameworks that kills it in game developement. C#, which is quite similar to Java, is very popular with the Unity engine.

Comment: It's funny that Unity is brought up. Because the hot path is for 100% C++ code.

Comment: @rustyx didn't know that. Doens't JIT compiler help with that?

Comment: No. Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); has not effect either

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, java s dedicated timer is better suited for this then mine, as mine was dependent on a while true loop. The rewriting with a javax.swing.Timer and the utilisation of Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync() upon each repaint solved the problem.